# celery call multi task once

Tags: celery, celery-task

I am using celery to implement async task, but I have tons of async task, so I have to call `task_func.delay()` multi times, my code is as following:

the registerd task:

```
@app.task()
def task1
    ...

@app.task()
def task2
    ...

@app.task()
def task3
    ...

@app.task()
def task4
    ...

@app.task()
def task5
    ...

@app.task()
def task6
    ...

.....
.....
```

I call the celery task in my other code such as in django views:

```
task1.delay()
task2.delay()
task3.delay()
task4.delay()
task5.delay()
task6.delay()
......
......
```

with the above code, each time I create a new celery task func, I have to call it with `delay()`, is there any way I can call all the task together?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is. [Canvas: Designing Workflows](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html) section in the Celery documentation explains how. In your particular case, if I understood it well, you need to use the [Chain](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains) primitive.